# JSF application scoped bean not injectable as managed property of ADF request scoped bean

Tags: jsf-2, nullpointerexception, oracle-adf, managed-bean, managed-property

**EDIT: This is an ADF application which uses JSF 2.0.**

I have an application-scoped managed bean which I am referencing in the managed property of a request-scoped bean. I am getting a NullPointerException when trying to access the app-scoped bean within the PostConstruct method of the request-scoped bean. I am not sure whether I am not understanding some fundamentals about when an app-scoped bean is available to a request-scoped bean, or whether I just have a mistake in my implementation.

App-scoped bean:

```
@ManagedBean(eager=true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class SecurityApplication {

    public String test() {
        return "test result";
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("In SecurityApplication.init");
    }
}
```

**EDIT: This is configured as a request-scoped managed bean in the adfc-config.xml file. This appears to be the problem since I have specified that the bean be managed by ADF, but used the JSF ManagedProperty annotation.**

Request-scoped bean:

```
public class UserSecurityCompanies {
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{securityApplication}")
    private SecurityApplication securityApplication;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("In UserSecurityCompanies.init");
        System.out.println("SecurityApp.Test():" + getSecurityApplication().test());
    }

    public SecurityApplication getSecurityApplication() {
        return securityApplication;
    }

    public void setSecurityApplication(SecurityApplication securityApplication) {
        this.securityApplication = securityApplication;
    }
}
```

The app-scoped bean is initialized during deployment of the app, but the NPE is thrown when getSecurityApplication().test() is called.

Steve

Comment: You left out one ambiguity. Who's managing that request scoped bean? If it's not JSF `@ManagedBean`, then `@ManagedProperty` obviously won't have any effect.

Comment: @BalusC - Thanks, I think that is pointing to the problem. I am using ADF which suggests that you configure beans in adfc-config.xml. I had the request scoped bean specified as a managed bean in that file, but the managed property is as shown above. I changed it so that it not registered as an ADF managed bean, but is a pure JSF ManagedBean and now I no longer get the NPE. So, it sounds like that solved that problem. I am however, getting other errors with ADF components not seeing properties in this bean, which makes me think mixing ADF with pure JSF managed beans is going to be a problem.

Comment: Have edited the original post to show what the problem was.

Comment: Bean is merely java class and its stay so regardless of framework, however managing adf framework in some other framework way is a real problem. You should give more explanation of what you doing and what you are trying to achieve. Also provide version of ADF you are using.

Comment: I think the real question is why you would like to use JSF 'only' managed beans instead of the ADF 'only' beans while using ADF.